# Want to create a document library in SharePoint 2013 using power shell which already has Library

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint site collection for ex:- http://bp1amsapt229:14146/gom/mdrcs

and Libraries in this site collection

1.General
2.Order

I want to create a new library  with name "W_General" having same property(you can say just duplicate of) as "General" library but the "W_General" should be empty(No documents only folders)

Please note that these library size are very big so template is not a good option. I want all this in power shell script. Please help

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using content types, then you'll need to re-create the source library's fields on the new library. This is pretty straightforward in PowerShell using an SPFieldCollection's `AddFieldAsXml` method, as in the example below:

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}
$web = get-spweb "http://bp1amsapt229:14146/gom/mdrcs"
$source = $web.lists["General"]
$newListId = $web.lists.add("W_General", $source.Description, $source.BaseTemplate)
$web.Update()
$list = $web.lists.GetList($newListId,$true)
$source.fields | ForEach-Object{
    if(-not $_.FromBaseType){
        write-host "adding $($_.Title)... " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $dest.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($_.SchemaXml);
        $dest.Update();
    }else{
        write-host "skipped adding $($_.Title)" -ForegroundColor Gray
    }
}
$source.Views | ForEach-Object{
    write-host "adding view '$($_.Title)'... "
    $dest.Views.Add($_.Title, $_.ViewFields, $_.Query, $_.RowLimit, $_.Paged, $_.DefaultView)
    $dest.Update()
}
$web.Dispose()
```

Notice that you'll also want to add views from the source library to the destination library if desired.

The above script does not duplicate any forms or workflows attached to the library.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your great solution. I am using content type and if i enable Parser i can use your solution.
Parser enabling code

if($web.ParserEnabled -ne $true)
{

$web.ParserEnabled = $true 
$web.Update()

}

Can anyone let me know if this can create any affect to my Record Library because it is in deactivate stage  by default. If i will disable it after creating my duplicate library will it rollback all the features which got activated after enabling it. What will it effect on document metadata. Please explain